How to add auto restart to a docker file
I need to add a 1-hour auto restart in my bot, how to do it in the following docker file:
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install git -y
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
    
RUN cd /
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -U -r requirements.txt
RUN mkdir /Anna-Auto-Filter
WORKDIR /Anna-Auto-Filter
COPY start.sh /start.sh
    
ENV UPSTREAM_REPO=""
    
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/start.sh"]

I am beginner in Docker, so can someone help me!

You should take a look at CRON  in Linux, it will allow to schedule running your scrip every minute/hour/day of your choice
